# Using Wordpress Authentication in Xcode

Tags: json, xcode, wordpress

I am building an IOS app that will use JSON API to get content.  How do I authenticate to a wordpress DB set in order to retrieve content that is only available after you've logged in.

Comment: I was able to achieve it by writting a php login authentication script on the server that was basically

Comment: I was able to achieve it by writing a php login authentication script on the server that was basically
<code>
<?php

require_once('wp-load.php'); 

$username = $password = "";

// check to see if its an email or username check
if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
   $user = get_user_by('email',$username);
 else
   $user = get_user_by('login',$username);
 
   $validUser = false;
 
   if ( $user and wp_check_password($password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) )
   $validUser = true;
 
?>

</code> 

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php require_once('wp-load.php'); 

$username = $password = ""; 

// check to see if its an email or username check 
if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
  $user = get_user_by('email',$username); 
 else 
  $user = get_user_by('login',$username); 
  
$validUser = false;  

if ( $user and wp_check_password($password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) ) 
 $validUser = true; 
?>
```